# How to change .keyup depending on a variable existence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a search form and ajax function inside .keyup can have different arguments, I want to check if I need to include this arg by checking if another value exists. Here is what I have now:

```
var delay = (function() {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
if (GLOBAL_VARS['link_id']) {
    search.keyup(function() {
        delay(function() {
            var query = search.val();
            ajaxGet(GLOBAL_VARS.distributorsSearchDistUrl, {
                'query': query,
                'pk' : GLOBAL_VARS['link_id']
            }, function(content) {
                $('#distributors').html(content);
                set_favorite();
            });
        }, 500);
    });
} else {
    search.keyup(function() {
        delay(function() {
            var query = search.val();
            ajaxGet(GLOBAL_VARS.distributorsSearchDistUrl, {
                'query': query                  
            }, function(content) {
                $('#distributors').html(content);
                set_favorite();
            });
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s6 right no-margin">
    <input id="search" type="text" class="validate" name="search">
    <label class="active" for="search">Search</label>
</div>
```

But this works for 1 time only, after I input any leter(`a` for example a get):

```
search_dist?query=a&pk=64
```

but when I enter aa(second input) I get:

```
search_dist?query=aa
```

without `pk`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a few more details? What code is executing this block? Is this block being executed more than once? What is `search` referring to and could you provide some html?

Comment: @pcnate, depending if I have `GLOBAL_VARS['link_id']` I want to add `'pk' : GLOBAL_VARS['link_id']` to context dictionary that a pass as an argument to ajaxGET function. If GLOBAL_VARS dictionary doesn't have 'link_id', i want to keep context dictionary `{'query': query}`

Comment: How are `delay` and `ajaxGet` defined?

Comment: @pcnate, ajaxGet is a library function, but basically it's just `$.get()` and I updated my answer for `delay()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I would suggest putting your conditions inside the `.keyup` callback. This will avoid the possibility of trying to bind the same event twice to the same element.

```
search.keyup(function() {
  delay(function() {
    var data = {
      query: search.val();
    }
    if (GLOBAL_VARS['link_id']) {
      data.pk = GLOBAL_VARS.link_id;
    }
    ajaxGet(GLOBAL_VARS.distributorsSearchDistUrl, data, function(content) {
      $('#distributors').html(content);
      set_favorite();
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

Working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pwRMAwNXnd1YExP32kg6)

Comment: No, this hasn't helped me. I tried to explain what I wanted in my comment.